# Remove item in list from hash lookup of memory location?

Tags: python, list, pointers, dictionary, memory

I have objects that each have a unique ID and these objects are inserted to various lists. These objects need to be removed frequently from the middle of its corresponding list which would be `O(n)` typically, so I'd like to keep their locations in a `dict` and retrieve the object's location in `O(1)` each time I want to remove it.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, lst_id, unique_id):
        self.lst_id = lst_id
        self.unique_id = unique_id

n1 = Node('a', 1)
n2 = Node('a', 2)
n3 = Node('b', 3)
node_lsts = {}
for node in [n1,n2,n3]:
    if node.lst_id in node_lsts:
        node_lsts[node.lst_id].append(node)
    else:
        node_lsts[node.lst_id] = [node]

nodes_hash = {n1.unique_id: n1, n2.unique_id: n2, n3.unique_id: n3}

ID_TO_REMOVE = 1
```

In example above, if I simply called `del nodes_hash[ID_TO_REMOVE]`, the corresponding object in `node_lsts` remains even though it is removed from the dictionary - how should I get it removed from its corresponding list in `O(1)`?

In C++ I can keep the pointers to list neighbors as node member variables (linked list) and look up a node by its memory address, get pointers to its neighbors, unlink that node from its neighbors (thereby removing it from the 'list') and finally free the node. I'm trying to replicate this behavior.

Comment: What do you frequently do with `nodes_lst_a`? Random access? Iteration? Appending to either end of the list?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something by why not remove it from `nodes_lst_a` using the index in `nodes_hash`? further, why don't you use *only* the hash?

Comment: @alfasin: `lst.pop(k)` is around *O(len(lst) - k)*, which isn't that great for random popping.

Comment: You just can't remove a `list` item in O(1) (except the last item).

Comment: @MichaelButscher Actually, you can remove any of the last 42 items in O(1).

Comment: @StefanPochmann Really? Anyway, if the linear searching for the right item to remove is added to the cost it can't be O(1).

Comment: @Blender I cleaned up the example. I frequently create new lists based on another identifier and use it to query neighbors of nodes tracked by my dictionary. e.g. I might sum the number of neighbors in front of the node.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Yes, really. But of course it's a joke. As long as I use a constant in the claim, it's correct. I could've just as well said you can remove any of the last 666 items in O(1).

Comment: @alfasin Yes, Blender is correct - I'll have to track and update the indices of all items each time I add a new node, if I wanted to pop it by index, otherwise I would need to walk through all the lists to find my node thus `O(n)` where `n` == number of nodes.

Comment: @Blender I wasn't referring to time complexity, I was referring to: "the corresponding object in node_lsts remains even though it is removed from the dictionary" - so I asked why doesn't she use the element she got from the dict.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Ah, "O()" definition is tricky.

Comment: @Katie You would have to find or create a linked list implementation to achieve this in Python. The standard library doesn't provide this (there is `deque` but this doesn't allow to reference nodes in the deque). Python's `list` is more like `std::vector<Object*>` in C++

Comment: @MichaelButscher Hmm, I fear so. It's a shame as I'd imagine Python's list implementation is a doubly linked list that preallocates in chunks, so it would a lot more efficient than my own homebrew linked list if it provided the right accessors/mutators.

Comment: @Katie Python's list isn't (doubly-linked chunks), but its deque is.

Comment: ^@StefanPochmann Ah cool, got it. Thanks.

Comment: How long do your lists get?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Hundreds usually. I think you're probably going to suggest that it's cheap to walk through the entire list? Anyway, I found a doubly linked list implementation (https://pythonhosted.org/llist/) which might serve what I need.

Comment: @Katie Yes, in the hundreds I suspect the naive solution might still be competitive.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Yeah agreed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a doubly linked list in Python:

```
class DoublyLinkedListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, unique_id, lst_id, left=None, right=None):
        self.unique_id, self.lst_id = unique_id, lst_id

        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def remove(self):
        if self.left is not None:
            self.left.right = self.right

        if self.right is not None:
            self.right.left = self.left

        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def append(self, node):
        node.left = self
        node.right = self.right

        if self.right is not None:
            self.right.left = node
            node.right = self.right

        self.right = node

    def prepend(self, node):
        node.left = self.left
        node.right = self

        if self.left is not None:
            self.left.right = node

        self.left = node

    def iter_left(self):
        current = self

        while current.left is not None:
            yield current.left
            current = current.left

    def iter_right(self):
        current = self

        while current.right is not None:
            yield current.right
            current = current.right
```

Being a linked list, this has *O(1)* insertion and deletion for any given node. If you can keep a reference to each node via a dictionary or some other better-suited data structure, this will allow you average case *O(1)* access and fast sequential iteration.

```
class ListContainer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lists = {}
        self.node_mapping = {}

    def append(self, node):
        if node.lst_id in self.lists:
            self.lists[node.lst_id].append(node)
        else:
            self.lists[node.lst_id] = node

        self.node_mapping[node.unique_id] = node

    def remove(self, node):
        ...
```

Note that this is all wasted effort if you're going to have only a few hundred elements in your lists. Pure-Python data structures probably will not be faster than your Python implementation's list data structures for so few elements. Big-O notation ignores the constant term, which can be prohibitively large if you're not dealing with enough elements (e.g. the [Coppersmith-Winograd algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm)).

Comment: Wow I can't believe how fast you coded this up. As noted in my comments, it seems like https://pythonhosted.org/llist/ has a stable C implementation of a doubly linked list.

Comment: (For future readers:) Regarding the constant term, yes, this was actually just a Python placeholder for future optimizations. I've had similar use cases in C++ where it was cheaper to use `std::vector` for cache locality over chasing pointers in a doubly-linked list. Unfortunately in Python I don't have enough control to go that far.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a list nested in a dict you can use a dict nested in a dict:

```
node[node.lst_id] = {node1.unique_id: node1, node2.unique_id: node2, ... }
```

Assuming `ID_TO_REMOVE` is a `unique_id` you can remove it with:

```
node_to_remove = nodes_hash[ID_TO_REMOVE]
del node_lsts[node_to_remove.lst_id][node_to_remove.unique_id]
```

Full code:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, lst_id, unique_id):
        self.lst_id = lst_id
        self.unique_id = unique_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return "[lst_id: {}, unique_id: {}]".format(self.lst_id, self.unique_id)

n1 = Node('a', 1)
n2 = Node('a', 2)
n3 = Node('b', 3)
node_lsts = {}
for node in [n1,n2,n3]:
    if not node.lst_id in node_lsts:
        node_lsts[node.lst_id] = {}
    node_lsts[node.lst_id][node.unique_id] = node

nodes_hash = {n1.unique_id: n1, n2.unique_id: n2, n3.unique_id: n3}

ID_TO_REMOVE = 1

print("node_lsts", node_lsts)
node_to_remove = nodes_hash[ID_TO_REMOVE]
print("node_to_remove", node_to_remove)
del node_lsts[node_to_remove.lst_id][node_to_remove.unique_id]
print("node_lsts", node_lsts)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
node_lsts {'a': {1: [lst_id: a, unique_id: 1], 2: [lst_id: a, unique_id: 2]}, 'b': {3: [lst_id: b, unique_id: 3]}}
node_to_remove [lst_id: a, unique_id: 1]
node_lsts {'a': {2: [lst_id: a, unique_id: 2]}, 'b': {3: [lst_id: b, unique_id: 3]}}
```

Since we're now using dictionaries everything is done in O(1) and we avoid the performance issue that was presented when we try to remove an element from a list.

Comment: Your response is technically correct but doesn't preserve the desired properties for why I put it in a list in the first place (append ordering, iteration etc.) Gave an upvote nevertheless.

Comment: @Katie you can use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if you care about the order of insertion.